# How to have a simple array as column data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I want one of the columns of a table to contain numbers separated either by space or comma or some other character. e.g. 113, 34, 56

I want to be able to query this table with a single number. e.g. 34 or 67 or 345

If the number I query the database with exists in the column, I want to have that (or those) records delivered.

Questions:

1. What should be my column's type? Is it varchar?
2. How should I query the database for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1: Yes, it is ok to be `VARCHAR`. You only need to take care of the size. It should be sufficient for your needs.

Question #2: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('34', col) > 0`

To use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), you must separate the values with comma, and no spaces, like this: `113,54,36`

Don't use the `LIKE` approach, as it will find "340" if you do `LIKE "%34%"`

Answer (score 7):

I must strongly advise against this.  The proper way to store them is in a table with a foreign key to the table holding the rest of the row, one row per value you would have stored in the space separated list.

It will cause you headaches down the road.

#### Table maintbl

```
id PRIMARY KEY
column1 VARCHAR
column2 VARCHAR
column3 VARCHAR
```

#### Table arraydata

```
main_id FOREIGN KEY to maintbl.id
value
```

Comment: I agree. But sometimes the need is so simple that it is OK to save the data in a comma-separated field.

Answer (score 3):

This does not seem like a great idea, as you wont be able to take advantage of the database indexes. Why do you need to have the numbers all in one column? A more efficient way would be to have it in a separate table with multiple rows (one per number). Michael's answer explains what this would look like (pretty simple relation).

If you insist on having it all in one column, then VARCHAR would do.

You would then have to query with:
SELECT * FROM TABLE where column = '34' OR column LIKE (',34%') OR column LIKE ('34,%')

That would cover the case where there is only one number, or the case where 34 is the first number, or where 34 is anywhere after the first number.

Comment: ah, nice. I never use the string functions and didn't know about it! I suppose the main advantage is that it only does string comparison once instead of three times.

Comment: My needs in this case are quite simple that is why I thought of this compact solution. Also I would like to believe that for a simple usage (where max.5 values are comma separated) queries will consume less CPU and memory compared to JOINs and foreign_keys. What do you think?

Comment: the problem is not the number of items in the list, is the number of rows you have to search through. Both the FIND_IN_SET and my LIKE solution have to scan all the rows in your table. A join with an index will do log(n) comparisons instead of n (where n is the number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a varchar column you're looking to use. You'll want to make sure you make it a long length so that you have enough room for all the numbers you're storing.

The query would look something like this:

```
Select * from table where numbers like '%34%' or numbers like '%67%' or numbers like '%345%';
```

Normally you'd be storing each of those numbers in a separate column so something like this not the most efficient. For a larger database I wouldn't recommend this, as indexes won't be used so the query won't perform too well with a large number of rows (>10,000)

I would recommend doing it this way. Assuming you have 1 table now called "table1"

table1 would have an integer that's a unique ID that is set to auto increment called "ID".

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
);
```

You would create a second table called "table2"

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idnumber` (`id`, `number`),
);
```

now you can properly query this like so:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.id, t2.number FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.number = 34 OR t2.number = 67;
```

This would allow you to know for sure you're selecting the numbers you are looking for.

Comment: What if I want to query for 34 and it returns 3489?

Comment: it very well could. unfortunately, by keeping your data in a long string like this you're subject to this. The only way you could change that is by storing it more formally, with 2 tables and a foreign key.

Comment: My answers shows how you would go about this. Its all terribly inefficient. Its a bad idea to do this. But it is possible, if you know what your number delimiter is.

Answer (score -1):

With spaces or comma's you're going to need VARCHAR, or one of the other text-based types.

You should be able to select what you want like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%34%'
```

Comment: that would match 134, 340, etc... see my answer below.